# Get derived class with base class function

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, derived-class

I need to do some equality checks with different types on a class hierarchy. In pseudo code:

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class ComplexType {};

class Property {};

class IntegerProperty : public Property {
public:
    int inner;
};

class StringProperty : public Property {
public:
    string inner;
};

class ComplexTypeProperty : public Property {
    ComplexType inner;
};


int main() {
    shared_ptr<Property> p1 = getSomewhere(); //this is in fact a pointer on IntegerProperty
    shared_ptr<Property> p2 = getSomewhere(); // this is in fact a pointer on StringProperty
    shared_ptr<Property> p3 = getSomewhere(); // this is in fact a pointer on CompleyTypeProperty

    ComplexType c;

    cout << ((*p1) == 2);
    cout << ((*p2) == "foo");
    cout << ((*p3) == c);
}
```

It it simple to provide a `operator==` for the derived classes, but I cannot cast before checking, because the type of `p1` and `p2` is not clear at compile time.

Another way I know is to write the `operator==` function in the `Property` base class and throw some exceptions if the type is wrong, but I want, that the `Property` class can be subclassed later without changing the code for `Property` and it will work, too.

Templating `Property` is also not (directly) possible, because e.g. in my code a `vector<shared_ptr<Property>>` has to exist.

Is there some (generic) way to implement main() to get the equality checks, so that later subclassing of `Property` without changing the class itself is possible?

Comment: If I have understood what you are asking for correctly, you should search the web for *double dispatch*.

Comment: @BoBTFish: If I get _double dispatch_ right, this could work with ComplexType, but not with Integer, String, ... because they do not share a common superclass.

Comment: Maybe operator== with std::variant or any? Just throwing out ideas...

Comment: I already use variant atm, but I don't know a good way to make it extendible later on.

Answer (score 0):

Have found some way of solving this. I'm not quite happy with the code. So if anyone has a better solution, please provide it.

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class ComplexType {
public:
    bool operator==(const ComplexType& i) {
        return true;
    }
};
inline ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const ComplexType& c) {
    os << "ComplexType";
    return os;
}

class Property {
public:
    virtual ~Property() {}
};

template <class T>
class LayerProperty : public Property {
private:
    T inner;

public:
    LayerProperty(T t) : inner(t) {}
    bool operator==(const T i) {
        return inner == i;
    }
};

int main() {
    shared_ptr<Property> p1 = make_shared<LayerProperty<int>>(LayerProperty<int>(5));
    shared_ptr<Property> p2 = make_shared<LayerProperty<string>>(LayerProperty<string>("foo"));
    shared_ptr<Property> p3 = make_shared<LayerProperty<ComplexType>>(LayerProperty<ComplexType>(ComplexType()));

    ComplexType c;

    cout << ((*dynamic_pointer_cast<LayerProperty<decltype(2)>>(p1)) == 2) << "\n";
    // special case std::string
    auto a = "foo";
    auto s = "";
    if (typeid(a) == typeid(s)) {
        cout << ((*dynamic_pointer_cast<LayerProperty<decltype(string(a))>>(p2)) == a) << "\n";
    }
    cout << ((*dynamic_pointer_cast<LayerProperty<decltype(c)>>(p3)) == c) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```